# Can't get this condition in ConcurrentLinkedQueue source code

Tags: java, concurrency

In the source code of ConcurrentLinkedQueue, in the `offer` method:

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
checkNotNull(e);
final Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e);

for (Node<E> t = tail, p = t;;) {
    Node<E> q = p.next;
    if (q == null) {
        // p is last node
        if (p.casNext(null, newNode)) {
                // Successful CAS is the linearization point
                // for e to become an element of this queue,
                // and for newNode to become "live".
                if (p != t) // hop two nodes at a time
                    casTail(t, newNode);  // Failure is OK.
                    return true;
            }
            // Lost CAS race to another thread; re-read next
        }
        else if (p == q)
            // We have fallen off list.  If tail is unchanged, it
            // will also be off-list, in which case we need to
            // jump to head, from which all live nodes are always
            // reachable.  Else the new tail is a better bet.
            p = (t != (t = tail)) ? t : head;
        else
            // Check for tail updates after two hops.
            p = (p != t && t != (t = tail)) ? t : q;
    }
}
```

at line 352, there is this condition:

```
p = (p != t && t != (t = tail)) ? t : q;
```

I know that code is to put p to the tail, but why use so complex code? and what does `(p != t && t != (t = tail))`mean? what the different between `t!=(t=tail))` and `t!=t`? should it always be false ?

Is there any materials can explain ConcurrentLinkedQueue clearly?

Comment: what are the types of `t` and `tail`?

Comment: `Tail` and `t` are `Node<E>` type inside the source code.

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting question, I [asked it more broadly there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319453/what-is-the-difference-between-a-b-and-a-a-b) and got a few answers. From what I can read on this topic:

`t != (t = tail)` is just a weird way to write:

```
if (t != tail)
    t = tail;
```

In short, you are comparing the value of `t` with the value of what is assigned to `t` on the right, here `tail`.

( All the credits go to [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran) for his understanding of the topic and his answer )

So to answer your question entirely:

- I don't know why they used so complex code.
- `(p != t && t != (t = tail))` means `if p != t and if t != tail t takes the tail value`
- Difference explained
- It should not be always false (obviously)

Answer (score -2):

so I would think that another thread could be updating between the operations that

```
t != (t = tail))
```

is checking, and it is testing for that.  it must be relying on atomics somehow to be useful

Edit:

to reply to Yassine Badache's, downvote *which seems to be correct*

```
t = tail
```

is an assignment operator

also, the

```
if
```

statement is used to branch code based on a condition, and

```
(x = y)
```

returns a reference to x, as in (obvious by inspection to anyone who has ever used c)

```
if ((p = fopen(f)) == NULL)
```

I think the OP is regarding Java's (or whoever) internal implementation of concurrency functionality

Edit:

and I think it's a bug in the implementation of Java and/or folly

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP asked what did that mean, and what was the difference between this and `t != t`.

Comment: @YassineBadache you're answer may be more applicable to c++, I think Java compares references and probably not much else. the issue is concurrency. you're assertion that the value is compared is simply wrong.  you would need to implement and use and isEqual() method

Comment: @YassineBadache also, your code: if (t != tail)
    t = tail; is backwards and exactly wrong

Comment: I think first step assign t = tail then do the t! = t . Am I right? the result is always be false

Comment: Try to run `int t=1; int tail=2;if (t != (t = tail)) System.out.println ("not equal");` as some people already recommended. you'll see that the order is backwards from this answer.

Comment: @YassineBadache you're right. i think it's folly

Comment: @AbdulAhad it is kind of counter-intuitive concerning boolean rules, I have to agree on this one.